# Discriminated union check on existence of a field?

Tags: typescript

What I want to do is pretty simple:

I have an type `Foo`, but there's cases where the Foo might be empty, so we have a union type with an empty object. (The use case here is actually with Redux, which doesn't let you have a redux state initalised as undefined).

```
interface Foo {
    id: string; 
    data: string; 
}

type PotentialFoo = Foo | {};
```

Later, when I'm using one of these `PotentialFoo`s, an easy way to check if it's a Foo or not, is to check if one of the fields exist.

But the TypeScript compiler doesn't like this.

```
const itemA: PotentialFoo = {
    id: "foo", 
    data :"data", 
}

const itemB: PotentialFoo = {}; 

function someFunct(item: PotentialFoo) {
    if (item.id) { //  Property 'id' does not exist on type '{}'.

        //handle it as a Foo. 
    }
}
```

Is there a way to to otherwise allow a discrimination here, like TypeScript allows in other cases?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Redux, but is your PotentialFoo either a Foo or an "incomplete" Foo? If so you might want to use the partial type: `function someFunct(item: Partial<Foo>) { ... }` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types

Comment: @Jasmonate no, it's not a Partial, because if it has the `id` field, then it also has the `data` field etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest solution in this case is to use an `in` check as a type guard:

```
function someFunct(item: PotentialFoo) {
    if ('id' in item) {

        item.data // ok
    }
}
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=19&ssc=2&pln=13&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyRywAJgFzIDOYUoA5gNzIHHKlxhyU10hMt8AXwIEwATwAOKAArpI4YHAA2GLAF40mZAB8cQ5gQToQNEpAC2AQUpyFYJau2a8hYmUoAiGJk8AaQTYOLmRyT2C4f0ERfCMTM2BLACFbeQhFFTVkFwNBAhgAVxAEBxNqdAsIVCKSgApEiAtU+0c1AEocVncYZFqAcjI+khBzRo7XLrYiBosAOgjkAHpF5HQAa0nkGKEgA)

Comment: I actually do like this answer better than the one I posted. It's much simpler. 

Can you explain why/how it works?

Comment: @dwjohnston The `in` operator is recognized as a type guard by the compiler. It will narrow the type of the tested variable (`item`) to any of the union constituents that contain the tested property (`id` in this case)

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use a TypeScript [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates), which is essentially to create a boolean function to determine the type, like you have here, but gives better compiler hints to TypeScript.

```
const itemA: PotentialFoo = {
    id: "foo", 
    data :"data", 
}

const itemB: PotentialFoo = {}; 

function isFoo(item: PotentialFoo) : item is Foo {
    return !!(item as Foo).id; 
}


function someFunct(item: PotentialFoo) {
    if (isFoo(item)) {
        //handle it as a Foo. 
    }
}
```